# Button text reverts when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button that throughout the program he changes his name.
 
original name is "line". 
 
is then renamed to "bar".

When is named "bar" and I press it executes the following code.
 
in the code is the variable _bt3.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         _bt1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
                         _viewBt1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
                         _bt2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
                         _viewBt2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
                         _bt3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-_viewBt3.frame.size.height+68);
                         _viewBt3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-_viewBt3.frame.size.height+68);
                         _bt4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
                         _viewBt4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
```

after that magically appears with your first name.

I just change the name of this button is pressed when the _bt2. 
I do not use any more part of code because the first name comes from the storyboard

when _bt2 is pressed runs the following code

```
- (IBAction)bt2Pressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"botao2");
    _bt3.titleLabel.text=@"Bar";
}
```

anyone know how to solve?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code that sets/changes the button text.

Comment: I just change the name of this button is pressed when the _bt2. 
I do not use any more part of code because the first name comes from the storyboard

Comment: @Pedro I don't understand your question. Can you please clearly say what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `_bt3.titleLabel.text` directly.  Don't do that.

A button has states: normal, highlighted, selected, and disabled.  It knows what its text should be for each state.  When `_bt3` changes state, it sets `_bt3.titleLabel.text`.  This overrides your change to `_bt3.titleLabel.text`.

If you don't set the text for a non-normal state, the button uses the text for the normal state.

When the user touches `_bt3`, `_bt3` changes its state to highlighted and sets `_bt3.titleLabel.text` to the text set for its highlighted state.  When the user stops touching `_bt3`, `_bt3` changes its state back to normal and sets `_bt3.titleLabel.text` to the text set for its normal state.

So instead of setting `_bt3.titleLabel.text` directly, you need to tell the button what text it should display in the normal state:

```
[_bt3 setTitle:@"Bar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```